# new records to add first row of data gridview

Tags: datagridview

In my application I try to fill my data grid view like this: Dim j1 As Integer = 0

```
SqlCommand cmdd1 = new SqlCommand("DashBordFetch1", con.connect); 
cmdd1.CommandType =CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdd1.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid;
da1.SelectCommand = cmdd1;
dr = cmdd1.ExecuteReader;
while (dr.Read) 
{ 
  {
     if (object.ReferenceEquals(dr("Car_Id"), DBNull.Value)) 
     {
        carid1 = "null";
     } 
     else 
     {
        carid1 = dr("Car_Id");
     }
     if (object.ReferenceEquals(dr("Plate_Source"), DBNull.Value)) 
     {
        platesource1 = "Null";
     } 
     else 
     {
           platesource1 = dr("Plate_Source");
     }
     string[] row1 = {
         carid1,
         platesource1 };
     DGVDeliverd.Rows.Add(row1);
   }
}

if (object.ReferenceEquals(dr("Value"), DBNull.Value)) 
 {
    value1 = 0;
 } 
 else 
     {
       value1 = dr("Value");}string[] row1 = {  carid1, platesource1,value1 
     }; 
 DGVDeliverd.Rows.Add(row1);
 if (value1 == 1)           
     {
    DGVDeliverd.Rows(j1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;} j1 += 1;
```

Aso i am using Timer..every 2 minutes timer will work. Some time new records will added to my datagridview. While adding new record that is adding to last row of my datagrid view, I want to add every time new records to my first row of datagridview.

How I can do this? i am using windows forms

Answer (score 0):

you can add it like this

```
 dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, value1, value2);
```

where `0` is your required index.

Comment: sir..i have one more condition in my datagridview,,after adding this code that is not working proper

Comment: if (value1 == 1) {
 DGVDeliverd.Rows(j1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
j1 += 1;

Answer (score 0):

**dataGridView.Rows.Add(value1, value2, value3);**
Or they can be,
**dataGridView.Rows.Add(variable1, variable2, variable3);**

thanks